# Многофайловые проекты С++

Tags: c++

Работал с многофайловыми проектами только в среде разработки. Сейчас работаю с g++ из GCC.

Сталкиваюсь с тем, что в примерах по С++ создают в среде разработки 2 файла: `name.h` и `name.cpp`. Затем в `name.cpp` подключают `name.h` — логично, ведь подтянутся заголовки.

Но в `main.cpp` подключают именно `name.h`, хотя тот содержит только заголовки. Это какой-то прикол среды разработки? Потому что по логике, чтобы в `main.cpp` была реализация функций, объявленных в `name.h`, нужно в файла `name.h` инклюдить `name.cpp`, а не наоборот.

И да, если создать в Linux 3 файла: `name.h`, `name.cpp`, `main.cpp`, затем в `name.h` создать прототипы, а в `name.cpp` — реализацию и подключить `name.h`, а только затем в `main.cpp` подключить `name.h`, то будет ругаться, что неопределенная ссылка на функцию из `name.h`.

Потому я и подумал, что это либо фича сред разработки — автоматом искать определение функций в `<name>.cpp` файлах, либо это фича компилятора.
Расскажите, будет интересно. А то я сейчас в `.h` файлы еще подключаю и `.cpp` файлы, иначе не работает просто...

Comment: Вы щас удивитесь, но компилятор может собирать больше одного .cpp файла в один исполняемый... Хотя обычно одного вполне достаточно.

Comment: и ? это вопрос на мой ответ?

Comment: *"уважаемые **погромисты**"* — однако оговорка по Фрейду :)

Answer (score 6):

Сборка исполняемого файла из исходного кода происходит в два этапа:

1. *Компиляция* (*трансляция*, в том числе препроцессирование, ассемблирование и собственно компиляция) — создаёт объектные файлы (`*.o`) из файлов реализации `*.cpp`
2. *Линковка* (*компоновка*) — связывает несколько объектных файлов в один исполняемый

При этом каждый *модуль трансляции* (читай файл `*.cpp`) компилируется **отдельно**. На применение такого подхода есть несколько причин, в частности это позволяет:

- сократить требование к ресурсам (в частности к памяти) необходимым для сборки
- не пересобирать всё заново при изменении только одного файла.
- комбинировать модули, написанные на разных языках

В классическом варианте сборка программы из нескольких файлов выглядит как-то так:

```
c++ -o main.o -c main.cpp
c++ -o name.o -c name.cpp
c++ -o prog main.o name.o   # здесь фактически вызывается команда ld
```

Обычно все эти команды запускаются не в ручную, а с помощью сторонних утилит на подобии `make` и надстройками над ними вроде `cmake` или `autotools`.

Современные (выпущенные, хотя бы, в этом веке) компиляторы также позволяют выполнить это всё в одно действие:

```
g++ -o prog main.cpp name.cpp
```

---

> А то я сейчас в .h файлы еще подключаю и .cpp файлы, иначе не работает просто...

Так делать, конечно, не стоит — это лишает смысла всю систему раздельной компиляции.

> Потому я и подумал, что это либо фича сред разработки - автоматом искать определение функций в .cpp файлах, либо это фича компилятора.

На самом деле, всё что делают среды разработки при сборке — это автоматизируют работу с утилитой `make` или её аналогами/надстройками.

Comment: Окей, я понял. Тогда зачем вообще указывать #include "name.h" если мы их отдельно компилируем и потом совмещаем их вместе.

Comment: @Proger2.0, эта необходимость как раз следствие того, что файлы компилируются раздельно: при компиляции `main.cpp` компилятор должен знать, что представляют из себя функции, определённые в `name.cpp`, но т.к. доступа к этому файлу в момент компиляции у него не будет, то их объявления надо как-то добавить в `main.cpp`. А чтобы вручную не прописывать эти объявления в каждом `*.cpp`-файле, в котором они используются, их выносятся в отдельный `*.h`-файл, который включается в другие... В c++20 также введена концепция «модуля», но пока они полноценно не поддерживаются и сейчас не об этом...

Answer (score 1):

Неопределенная ссылка на функцию возникает потому, что Вы не указали где именно искать реализацию кода.

Случай include обрабатывает предпроцессор: в место где он указан вставляется весь .h файл, а потом все передается компилятору.

Дальше сами фунции нужно подгрузить - это может делаться на 2х следующих этапах.

На этапе компиляции cpp файл собирается в машинный код. Если указать несколько файлов, то машинный код собирается для каждого файла и объединяется в один выходной файл, который пока ещё не может запускаться, но имеет все функции из всех ваших файлов.

В Вашем примере можно просто:

```
g++ name.cpp main.cpp ....
```

Хотя можно и каждый файл компилировать отдельно, а потом собрать на третьем этапе.

IDE и проекты ориентированны на среду сборки, которая настраивается для сборки всех файлов.

На этапе линковки машинные коды соединяются в блоки структуры PE (Windows) или ELF (Linux) исполняемого файла. Тут недостающие функции можно загрузить из библиотек. Например Вы оформили name.h, name.cpp библиотекой и через опции -L и -l линковщик узнает что их можно найти в библиотеке.

П.С. пропустил этап. Между проепроцессингом и линковкой есть ещё ассемблер.

Итого вызов `g++` без параметров на самом деле вызывает 4 программы компилятора

cpp — препроцессор - подстановка инклудов

as — ассемблер

g++ — сам компилятор - нужно вызвать для каждого .cpp файла (по одному или пачкой) чтоб все заработало

ld — линкер - упаковывает машинные коды в экзешник, указывает в каких дллках искать то что не хватает.

ППС. [Вот подробная статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/478124/), вроде хорошо написанно.